# date without dashes and colons ms access + can date be part of autonumber?

Tags: microsoft-access, date-time, date, forms

I want the date (22-12-2018) without dashes and colons in Ms Access for a field.
How can I achieve it? Also is there some way to change the alignment i.e. (22-12-2018) should be 22122018 or 12222018 or 20181222.

I want to include it (date) to be part of Autonumber in records for field. Is that achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the date format described in your question, use the `Format` function with the following arguments:

```
Format(Date(), "ddmmyyyy")
```

e.g.:

```
?Format(Date(), "ddmmyyyy")
08062019
```

---

Whilst you can change the display format of an AutoNumber to display static content surrounding the incrementing section of the field, by changing the `Format` property to something like:

```
"ID"000
```

This does not change the actual data held by the field, but only the way that such data is *displayed* by the field (the field will still contain an incrementing Long Integer).

You also cannot use expressions within this `Format` property, and so you would not be able to insert the current date as a prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to one part:

Format(Date(), "mmddyy")

But my question still remains for the date to be part of autonumber, let me know if it can achieved?